# Let $G$ be a finite group with prime order $p$ and $H$ a finite group of prime order $q$. How many homomorphisms $f: G \to H$ are there?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

> Let $G$ be a finite group with prime order $p$ and $H$ a finite group of prime order $q$ such that $p \ne q$. How many homomorphisms $f: G \to H$ are there?

If $|G|=p$, then for $g \in G$ we have that $g^p=e_G$. If $f$ is a homomorphism, then $f(e_G)=e_H$ which means that $f(g^p)=f(g)^p=e_H$, thus $p$ must divide the order of $H$. That is we have $p \mid q$. I think that this implies that $p=q$ which contradicts the fact that $p \ne q$ so there are no homomorphisms?

Comment: You can have the order of $f(g)$ to be $1$, which divides $q$. The homomorphism $f(x)=e_H$ falls in this case. The step in your argument that is incorrect is deducing from $f(g)^p=e_H$ that $p|q$. You do get that the order of $f(g)$ divides $q$ and that the order of $f(g)$ divides $p$. The case of its order being $p$ fits the rest of your argument, but you still have the case of order $1$.

Comment: Groups always have the trivial homomorphism which sends everything to the identity.  You lose that property if you go up to rings with unity and require your homomorphism to preserve the multiplicative identity

Answer (score 2):

More generally,  let $G,H$ be finite groups of relatively prime order.   Then there is only the trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $H$.

The argument is just the same:   for any $g\in G$, and any homomorphism $h:G\to H$,  we have that the order of $h(g)$ divides both the order of $G$ and of $H$.  Thus $h(g)=e$.